# Cannot send parse push notification

Tags: parse-platform

i have been parse for a while and it is working fine. Now iam facing a problem on sending push notification. This i have done

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: application id" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: REST_API_KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "channels":[''],
        "data": {
          "alert": "The Giants won against the Mets 2-3."
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

I meant to send a broadcast message. But in parse console it shows

```
Targeting :
channels includes any of , or nil
deviceType is any of "android", "winphone", or "js"
Sending date :
November 26th, 2013 at 4:32 PM
Expiration :
None
Full target :
{ "channels": { "$in": [ ] }, "deviceType": { "$in": [ "android", "winphone", "js" ] } }
Full data :
{ "alert": "The Giants won against the Mets 2-3." }
```

Iam not able to figure from where is '$in' key is been assigned for full target? 
Sending pushes using parse console is working fine.

How it can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Its advanced targeting - REST API always ends up doing that - $in means the channels the push is to be send to... I am not 100% sure but you need to add a where: {} in your call if you want to broadcast to all... Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ok so thats '$in' is meant to be,was not aware of it and i had solved the issue it was the single quotes that created the issue. Replaced with double quotes and got the thing. Cheers...!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be silly but it made me nuts for hours. Simply it was the single quotes in channel array causing the problem. Changed to double quotes solved my issue.